# python-docx won't install ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700)

Tags: python, python-docx, anaconda3

Not sure what is going on here, but I get the following error when trying to install python-docx on my server:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::lxml-4.5.0-py38hbb43d70_1'.
[Errno 13] Pewrmission denied: '.../anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml/ElementInclude.py
```

The thing is, there is no such file that I can find in that location, so not sure what this is all about, any help would be appreciated, I've not found anything at all on google relating to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved, but my solution was to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it. This error occurred because the original error advised me to rename or manually delete the ElementInclude.py file. So I did that knowing it was only the Anaconda distribution not a linux system file, but it broke the my website anyway. The fault initially cropped up, as we were trying to use Anaconda on another account whilst it was installed on my account. Anaconda3 is now installed in root so that it is accessible by all users now. I still had to set it to PATH on each of the two accounts that wanted access, but doing that python-docx installed with no issues.